# Guessing Game and Number Comparison

Tags: c#, algorithm

I am not understanding how to compare the numbers in the file with the number that has been passed from the function.

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace Guess_Game
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int quantity;
        int min, max;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Quantity of Numbers : ");
        quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Maximum and Minimum Number that you wish to be in your file : \n");
        Console.WriteLine("MIN : ");
        min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("MAX : ");
        max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Now, Guess the Number : ");
        int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Now Guess a Number That already contains in a File : ");
         number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         GuessGame(min, max, quantity, number);

        //if(number!= // number not equal to that number that contains in a file.. how to write it in that 
            //if condition..
    }

    static void GuessGame(int min,int max,int quantity,int number)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"D:\nasir\Guess Game\Guess Game\bin\Debug\ Guess Game.txt");

        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            int temp = r.Next(min, max);
            sw.WriteLine(temp);
        }
       // while(number != sw.WriteLine())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Your Guess is Wrong!");
        }
        sw.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); it will blow up if I enter "A" :) - always use tryparse, never believe in the user!

Comment: i dont understand the differnce b/w parse and try parse.. parse converts the number that all i knw abt it.. but what does try parse do.. can u explain plx?

Comment: you can parse a string to an int safely using TryParse method.I mean it doesn't throw an exception but it returns a boolean if it's successful and the value is returned in an out parameter.
It's helpful if your program can continue working if a string value is not an integer anyway but if it's not acceptable you'd better use Parse.

Answer (score 2):

You're rolling dice every time (unfair, IMO) and doesn't read that file, but just writes it. Let's start with this:

```
static void Main()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    bool lucky = false;
    int maxTries, minValue, maxValue, guess = 0;

    GetInput("Enter number of tries: ", out maxTries);
    GetInput("Enter minimum number : ", out minValue);
    GetInput("Enter maximum number : ", out maxValue);

    int magical = r.Next(minValue, maxValue); // only once
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxTries; i++)
    {
        GetInput("Enter your guess : ", out guess);
        if (guess == magical)
        {
            lucky = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("you.Lucky = {0};", lucky);
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static void GetInput(string text, out int variable)
{
    do Console.Write(text);          // avoiding stackoverflow.com scroll
    while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out variable));
}
```

If you want to get your numbers from a file, try something like:

```
List<int> magicals = new List<int>();
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("GuessGame.txt"))
{
    int magical = 0;
    string line = "";
    while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(line = reader.ReadLine()))
    {
        if (Int32.TryParse(line, out magical))
            magicals.Add(magical);
    }
}
```

and test is like this:

```
if(magicals.Contains(guess))
```

Comment: I would believe this is some kind'a homework ... it's not good to show/present an entire solution, let the fellow learn something! valeu? :)

Comment: @balexandre, doesn't looks like homework for me, but I understood your point. curintia :)

Comment: So you think he's solving a real-world problem, then?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your file is ...

image that is:

```
12
17
9
```

then you use:

```
string[] fileNumbers = File.ReadAllLines("C:\MyGuessNumbers.txt");
```

so in fileNumbers you get all numbers into a string array, just loop and compare :)

**TRY PARSE vs PARSE**

from your code:

```
int quantity;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Quantity of Numbers : ");
quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

if the Console.ReadLine() is not an integer you will get an Exception saying that the object can not be parsed, witch is write, an "A" is a string and not an integer

if you use

```
int quantity = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter the Quantity of Numbers : ");
while(! int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out quantity) )
   Console.WriteLine("That does not seam to be an integer, please only use numbers!\nEnter the Quantity of Numbers : ");
```

this will validate if that is a number, as it will TRY parsing and it will return a boolean TRUE or FALSE if it parsed the integer successfully or not.

in this example, I loop until the user enters a number, in progaming language, while the TryParse returns false.

Comment: yea. as u can c in my program, i have generated random numbers.. that are stored in my .txt file extention..

Comment: if your program have already the numbers, why are you stuffing them into a file for the next line of code read that file??? it's much quicker to just return all the random numbers and compare no?

Comment: no no no... i have generated random number class.. every time a execute my program, there will be new series of random numbers that will be stored in a path that is given..

Answer (score 0):

you have a small fault that you compare the integer with the filewriter `sw` so the guess will be allways wrong.
 so fristly  close the connection after you enter  your guess the add a file reader:

```
 sw.Close();      
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:Guess Game.txt");
```

then make the compareson

as a gift i improve your hall code enjoy

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.IO;

 namespace Guess_Game
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int quantity;
        int min, max;
        int[] number = new int[10];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Quantity of Numbers : ");
        quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("Enter the Maximum and Minimum Number t \n");
        Console.WriteLine("MIN : ");
        min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("MAX : ");
        max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Now, Guess the {0}Number : ", i + 1);
            number[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        GuessGame(min, max, quantity, number);

        //if(number!= // number not equal to that number that contains in a file.. how to write it in that 
        //if condition..
    }

    static void GuessGame(int min, int max, int quantity, int[] number)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C: Guess Game.txt");

        int[] temp = new int[quantity];
        for (int i = 0; i < quantity; i++)
        {
            temp[i] = r.Next(min, max);
            sw.WriteLine(temp[i]);

        }
        sw.Close();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C: Guess Game.txt");
        int trying = 3;
        int[] guess = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i <= quantity; i++)
            guess[i] = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < quantity;i++ )
            for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
                if (number[j] != guess[i] )
                {


         System.Console.WriteLine("you have wrong Answer,you have {0} try ", trying--);
                    for (int k = 0; k < quantity; k++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("you {0} Number is", k+1);
                        number[k] = Convert.ToInt32(System.Console.ReadLine());
                    }

                    if(trying==0)

                    for (j = 0; j <quantity; j++)
           Console.WriteLine("Your Guess is right! the right answer is{0} ", guess[j]);




                }

        for (int j = 0; j < quantity; j++)
         Console.WriteLine("Your Guess is right! the right answer is{0} ", guess[j]);

  Console.ReadLine();  } 
}
}
```

Comment: sorry  I edit it now it gives you a mseeage if your guess is right